# FrameAttachedToGraph error when spawning robot from URDF

Tags: ros, gazebo-11, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to spawn franka emika panda's arm and hand (or even just the arm) from gazebo_ros spawn model, but the scene stays empty, the model list on the left part of the gui lists the name of my model but without any child and I get this error :

```
[Err] [Model.cc:99] Error Code 23 Msg: FrameAttachedToGraph error, Non-LINK vertex with name [__model__] is disconnected; it should have 1 outgoing edge in MODEL attached_to graph.  
[Err] [Model.cc:99] Error Code 23 Msg: Graph has __model__ scope but sink vertex named [__model__] does not have FrameType LINK when starting from vertex with name [__model__].
```

I can trace back this error to the **validateFrameAttachedToGraph** function of FrameSemantics.cc in the sdfFromat library but I have no idea how to solve that. I don't think my urdf is broken, it's the urdf.xacro file from franka_ros. Has anyone ever encountered this issue ?

I am using Gazebo 11.1.0 with Ros Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04.1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26054/frameattachedtograph-error-when-spawning-robot-from-urdf/) by [dondel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/35544/dondel/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

See https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/issues/2869

sdf ignores links without intertia

---

Originally posted by [dondel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/35544/dondel/) with karma: 1 on 2020-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0